# Add country, state dropdown to user registrtaion

Tags: users

i am creating a user registration form. In this i want to add fields for country, state, area and the fields are dependent on each other i.e. state depends on country and area depends on state. Is there any module in drupal or any way to integrate it with user registration form.

Comment: Questions about the modules to use should show an effort in finding the right module, which means: looking on drupal.org for the module, reporting here the tested modules and why they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module, which gives what you want, but you to have create vocabulary for it.

> This module defines the "hierarchical_select" form element, which is a greatly enhanced way for letting the user select items in a hierarchy.
>
> Hierarchical Select has the ability to save the entire lineage of a selection or only the "deepest" selection. You can configure it to force the user to make a selection as deep as possible in the tree, or allow the user to select an item anywhere in the tree. Levels can be labeled, you can configure limit the number of items that can be selected, configure a title for the dropbox, choose a site-wide animation delay, and so on. You can even create new items and levels through Hierarchical Select!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve that by using the [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module

> Define dependencies between fields based on their states and values.

check out  [A Drupal Dropdown List of Countries, States, Cities](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/dropdown-list/) for more info

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve that by using custom module like follows

```
<?php
/**
* hook_form_alter
*/
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
if($form_id == 'my_node_form') {

$country_default_value =$form_state['values']['field_cmn_city']['und']['0']['value'];
$state_default_value = $form_state['values']['field_cmn_state']['und']['0']['value'];
$city_default_value = $form_state['values']['field_cmn_city']['und']['0']['value'];

$country_options = _get_location('country');
$selected_country = $country_default_value;
$form['field_cmn_country']['und']['#options'] = $country_options;
$form['field_cmn_country']['und']['#default_value'] = $selected_country;
$form['field_cmn_country']['und']['#ajax'] = array(
'callback' => 'field_cmn_country_callback',
'wrapper' => 'field_cmn_state_replace',
);

$state_options = _get_location('state', $selected_country);// get state
$selected_state = $state_default_value;

$form['field_cmn_state']['und']['#prefix'] = '';
$form['field_cmn_state']['und']['#suffix'] = '';
$form['field_cmn_state']['und']['#options'] = $state_options;
$form['field_cmn_state']['und']['#default_value'] = $selected_state;

$form['field_cmn_state']['und']['#ajax'] = array(
'callback' => 'field_cmn_state_callback',
'wrapper' => 'field_cmn_city_replace',
);

$city_options = _get_location('city', $selected_state, $country_default_value);
$form['field_cmn_city']['und']['#prefix'] = '';
$form['field_cmn_city']['und']['#suffix'] = '';
$form['field_cmn_city']['und']['#options'] = $city_options;
$form['field_cmn_city']['und']['#default_value'] = $city_default_value;

}
}

function _get_location($type, $location_id = NULL, $country_id = NULL) {
switch ($type) {
case 'country':

return $country_options;
break;

case 'state':
return $state_options;
break;

case 'city':
return $city_options;
break;

}
// ajax country callback
function field_cmn_country_callback($form, $form_state) {

$form_field_state =$form['field_cmn_state'];
$form_field_city = $form['field_cmn_city'];

return array(
'#type' => 'ajax',
'#commands' => array(
ajax_command_replace("#field_cmn_state_replace", render($form_field_state)),
ajax_command_replace("#field_cmn_city_replace", render($form_field_city))
)
);

}
//ajax state callback
function field_cmn_state_callback($form, $form_state) {

return $form['field_cmn_city'];
}
?>
```

check [source](http://drupaldeveloper.in/codelet/drupal-country-dependant-city-dropdowns) for more info

Answer (score 0):

How about the [Address Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield) module ?

> Address Field defines a new field type to store international postal addresses, implementing a subset of the top-level address elements defined in the [xNAL standard](http://xml.coverpages.org/xnal.html).

It has country and state, and you may be able to override it with a small custom module to add 'area'

Comment: can i use this with profile2 module?

Comment: I don't use it myself, but I would imagine they are interoperable.