# How to select state on country bases in drupal webform

Tags: webforms

How to select the state on country bases in drupal.I have different country and states now I want to select the state on the country bases. I have installed the webform module and webform conditional field module. How I can do this task.

Comment: Do you mean have a different set of states depending on what country you select?

Comment: Yes, I have to select states on country bases @Matt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add country, state dropdown to user registrtaion](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/121674/add-country-state-dropdown-to-user-registrtaion)

Comment: I have to do this in webform with Id like 1123|Andorra @JapoDomingo

Comment: Yup there are options in the answers on methods of importing into your taxonomy. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Webform Simple Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_shs) and the [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) modules; just create a vocabulary and add countries and states hierarchically.

If you don't have vocabularies for countries and states, using the [Taxonomy Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager) module helps you to import countries and states from a simple list like the following.

```
United Stated
- Alabama
- Washington
Iran
- Tehran
India
- Mbambi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the [Webform Simple Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_shs) and the [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) modules. In this way, you can make the latter module work with the Webform module.

If you need a list of countries/states, you can get it from [Lists of Options](https://www.drupal.org/node/2834428). [This is a tutorial](https://nielsdefeyter.nl/archive/2012/how-import-hierarchical-taxonomies-drupal-7) on how to import a list of countries/states into your vocabularies using the [Taxonomy CSV Import Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv) module.